# How to change Artifactory top banner green color?

Tags: artifactory

We use the Artifactory OSS 4.15.0 version (latest at the moment of this writing).

We can change the logo but are unable to change the background color that stays green on the top banner (where there is the logo, the search, the name of the logged in user and the help).

How to change this top banner color that is green at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code, as you are on the OSS version, but there is no out of the box option in Artifactory to change the color of the header.